# Assigning DATEADD() function to a variable

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am trying to fill a table with test date data(with a loop) in MySQL. But when I try to create random dates by assigning the function `DATE_ADD()` to a variable, it gives me a syntax error. Below is the statement I included inside my procedure loop.

```
SELECT @dat = DATE_ADD('2020-01-01', INTERVAL 999 * RAND() DAY);  // Tried  using  SET @dat = ... too
```

Comment: Use either `:=` unambiguous assigning operator or (better) SELECT .. INTO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When assigning using `SET`, then `=` is used.

When assigning using `SELECT`, then `:=` is used.

Your query is a boolean comparison using the equality operator.  Try:

```
SELECT @dat := DATE_ADD('2020-01-01', INTERVAL 999 * RAND() DAY);
```

Comment: The query itself is functional now, but it still gives me a syntax error, any ideas, sir?

Comment: @EikichiOnizuka . .  This works (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4dac0f3a7081d9439ee03544fc2d6ebe) and answers the question you have here.  If you have a different question, then ask a *new* question, providing sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation.

Comment: Understood. Thanks, sir.